# Error when load mkvtoolnix-gui as "mkvtoolnix-gui: symbol lookup error: mkvtoolnix-gui: undefined symbol"

Tags: c++, linux, boost, archlinux

This is the error I got when I start mkvtoolnix-gui:

> mkvtoolnix-gui: symbol lookup error: mkvtoolnix-gui: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost16re_detail_10640012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISC_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE14construct_initERKNS_11basic_regexIcSJ_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running the decorated symbol through `c++filt` reveals:

```
$ echo _ZN5boost16re_detail_10640012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISC_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE14construct_initERKNS_11basic_regexIcSJ_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE | c++filt
boost::re_detail_106400::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)
```

I'm not a Boost guy, but I'm guessing you need to install Boost.Regex for Arch.

---

Here's what they are called under Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ apt-cache search boost-regex
libboost-regex1.58.0 - regular expression library for C++
libboost-regex-dev - regular expression library for C++ (default version)
libboost-regex1.58-dev - regular expression library for C++
```

Here's what they are called under Fedora 26:

```
$ dnf search boost-regex
Last metadata expiration check: 1 day, 12:41:53 ago on Fri 14 Jul 2017 03:00:18 AM EDT.
====================== Name Exactly Matched: boost-regex =======================
boost-regex.i686 : Run-time component of boost regular expression library
boost-regex.x86_64 : Run-time component of boost regular expression library
```

I can't figure out what they are called in Arch. Pacman is returning 0 results for the following. Maybe its in `extra/boost-libs 1.64.0-4`.

- `pacman -Ss boost-regex`
- `pacman -Ss 'boost-regex*'`
- `pacman -Ss boost | grep -i regex`
- `pacman -Ss Boost | grep -i regex`